# SIGABRT Because of the FBSDK

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, firebase, fbsdk

So I noticed that the FBSDK is affecting a lot the storyboard, so I'll present you what I want to do and when I open up the app why it presents the SIGABRT.

Here is want I want to perform:

```
func switchStoryboard() {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginConnection", sender: self)

}
```

This is how I want it to be performed:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {
        print("User is logged in")
    }
    else {
        self.switchStoryboard()
    }
```

Where the problem is supposed to be located at:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if (error != nil){
        print(error)
        return
    }
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("Failed to get graph request", err)
            return
        }
        print(result)
    }
```

Well, I have no clue. I tried to debug, everything seems ok but it confuses me a lot, hopes someone here had the same mistake and could help me with this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

fixed with:

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)
            }
            self.switchStoryboard()
            print("user is not signed in")
        })
    }
```

problem is that the function of `self.switchStoryboard()` is not working as well as the both `print`'s